# How to access array of drawables from a method

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have researched similar problems but none is a fit for this problem. Am trying to access the arrays of drawables from the method name called nextQuestion(), but i keep getting the error cannot resolve symbol 'ballArray' any help please. I just feel that this should work but don't know why. Here is my code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    ImageView mBallDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int quote;

        mBallDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_eightBall);
        Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        Button prevbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevbutton);

         final int[] ballArray = {
                R.drawable.ball1,
                R.drawable.ball2,
                R.drawable.ball3,
                R.drawable.ball4,
                R.drawable.ball5
        };

        //next button
        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                nextQuestion();

            }
        });



        //previous button
        prevbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                prevQuestion();
            }
        });

    }

    private void nextQuestion(){
        mBallDisplay.setImageResource(ballArray[4]);
    }

    private void prevQuestion(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't access `ballArray` from within `nextQuestion()` is because it's declared in a separate method. If you want it accessible from within `nextQuestion()`, you would need to make it visible at that level:

```
ImageView mBallDisplay;

final int[] ballArray = {
  R.drawable.ball1,
  R.drawable.ball2,
  R.drawable.ball3,
  R.drawable.ball4,
  R.drawable.ball5
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int quote;

    mBallDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_eightBall);
    Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    Button prevbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevbutton);

    //next button
    nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            nextQuestion();

        }
    });



    //previous button
    prevbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            prevQuestion();
        }
    });

}

private void nextQuestion(){
    mBallDisplay.setImageResource(ballArray[4]);
}

private void prevQuestion(){

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the correct code, because i tried out your idea and ran into more issues. I had problem with the method not visible

Comment: @PacPac You'd have to post the code you have and the exact error. It sounds like there might be more than one issue with the code you originally posted, and the first one is hiding the others.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mBallDisplay;

    int[] ballArray = {
                R.drawable.ball1,
                R.drawable.ball2,
                R.drawable.ball3,
                R.drawable.ball4,
                R.drawable.ball5
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int quote;

        mBallDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_eightBall);
        Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
        Button prevbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevbutton);

        //next button
        nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                nextQuestion();

            }
        });

        //previous button
        prevbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                prevQuestion();
            }
        });

    }

    private void nextQuestion(){
        mBallDisplay.setImageResource(ballArray[4]);
    }

    private void prevQuestion(){

    }

}
```